# Punctuation before without

Tags: punctuation, commas

The introduction to *The Meditations of the Emperor Marcus Aurelius Antoninus*,  which can be [read online](https://oll.libertyfund.org/title/silverthorne-the-meditations-of-the-emperor-marcus-aurelius-antoninus-2008?html=true), contains this sentence:

> Some of these meditations cannot well be **apprehended, without** a considerable acquaintance with the philosophy and stile of the Stoics:

why there is a comma before without ?

Comment: It probably needn't be there.  But to get an answer you need to **tell us the name of the author and source of this quote** and if possible **edit to make a link to the source**.  Thank you.

Comment: Anyway, the style of writing looks old-fashioned.  I suspect this is an old text and the rules and conventions that we now have for punctuation were not developed hundreds of years ago.

Comment: A web search did not find this exact sentence.

Comment: That's because the OP has updated some of the spelling.  It is from Hutcheson’s 1742 introduction to the the [Meditations of Marcus Aurelius](https://oll.libertyfund.org/title/silverthorne-the-meditations-of-the-emperor-marcus-aurelius-antoninus-2008?html=true)